# partitioning problem: windows occupies 2 partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows, multi-boot

I have an HP TouchSmart^310 PC with Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7 on it. I know that every computer can have *four* primary partitions. This is what I get with `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 121601 cilindri, totale 1953525168 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0xe9bc6db9

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2   *      206848  1518526463   759159808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1518528510  1910609919   196040705    5  Esteso
/dev/sda4      1910609920  1953521663    21455872    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5      1518528512  1902747647   192109568   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1902749696  1910609919     3930112   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

/dev/sda2 is Windows 7 with label OS, /dev/sda4 is Ubuntu with no label and /dev/sda4 is the HP RECOVERY ENVIRONMENT. But I can't figure what is /dev/sda1: every time I boot my PC, in GRUB I can see:

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu with advanced settings
- Windows 7
- Windows 8 (???)
- HP Recovery Environment

I don't know if Windows needs /dev/sda1 for booting, or is the partition I left there when I installed the Windows 8 Consumer Preview. I'm asking this because I need to create another partition, neither I want to convert to GPT. Can I remove /dev/sda1?

Comment: Your question is really about Windows, it's off-topic here. As far as Ubuntu is concerned, you can remove `/dev/sda1`, but it may destroy your Windows installation, we wouldn't know. I've flagged it for migration to [su]. Please do not repost unless your question gets closed here.

Comment: Small typo - Ubuntu and HP Recovery aren't sharing /dev/sda4.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/sda1` is most likely Windows 7's  [system partition](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-are-system-partitions-and-boot-partitions) and Windows 7 won't boot without it.

It's unlikely that it's a leftover from the Windows 8 Consumer Preview, since Windows 8 increased the size of the system partiton from 100 MiB to 350 MiB ([source](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5630/indepth-with-the-windows-8-consumer-preview/2)).

Although it's true that you can't create more than four primary partitions, you can create additional logical partitions (`/dev/sda7`, etc.) inside your extended partition (`/dev/sda3`). For most purposes, it makes no difference if you use a primary or a logical partition.

Comment: I once had my computer quad-booting (XP, Vista, 7 RC, Linux) on one disk. With an extended partition, doing such a thing is quite easy.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand: can you explain me what the second thing you've said (increasing p. size from 100mib to 350mib) can influence my partitioning?

Comment: You said *I don't know if Windows needs /dev/sda1 for booting, or is the partition I left there when I installed the Windows 8 Consumer Preview.* Since Windows 7's system partition is 100 MiB big and Windows 8's is 350 MiB, your system partition belongs to Windows 7, not 8.